# Site iPhone layout breaking on 1 page but not another similar page?

Tags: iphone, layout

http://littlegiant.co.nz/preview/tradeworks/

If you look at the home page on an iPhone you will see the menu drops down to the next line, but if you go to any of the other pages it doesn't.

What could be causing this?